# Setting an index limit in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, indexing, sqlalchemy

I would like to set up a maximum limit for an index within a `Column` definition or just through the `Index` constructor but I don't seem to find a way to achieve it.

Basically, I would like to simulate this MySQL behaviour:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  some_text varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY some_text (some_text(1024)), # <- this line
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

In SQLAlchemy I would have something like:

```
class SomeTable(BaseModel):
  __tablename__ = 'some_table'
  __seqname__ = 'some_table_id_seq'

  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(11), sa.Sequence(__seqname__), primary_key=True)
  some_text = sa.Column(sa.String(2048), index=True) # <- this line
```

but I can't find anything that would suggest the limit of the index can be customised. Something like:

```
some_text = sa.Column(sa.String(2048), index=True, index_length=1024)
```

I guess since this option for the `Column` constructor is just an alias for the `Index` constructor, is there a custom param to include in the `Index` constructor to allow this setting?

Thanks!

Comment: If you must 'prefix' an index, you may as well make the length just long enough to usually distinguish the rows.  (1024 smells excessive.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can do something like:

```
class SomeTable(BaseModel):
  __tablename__ = 'some_table'
  __seqname__ = 'some_table_id_seq'
  __table_args__ = (
      sa.Index("idx_some_text", "some_text", mysql_length=1024),
  )
  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(11), sa.Sequence(__seqname__), primary_key=True)
  some_text = sa.Column(sa.String(2048))
```

Reference:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#index-length

Comment: What if I also need `some_text` to have `unique=True`?

Answer (score 0):

For a composite index you can use:

```
class SomeTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer(11), primary_key=True)
    text_a = Column(TEXT(1024))
    text_b = Column(TEXT(2048))

    __table_args__ = (
        Index("idx_some_table", "id", "text_a", "text_b", mysql_length={'text_a': 64, 'text_b': 32}),
    )
```